# How to unextend Extendables framework, keeping just the logger and Jasmine test functionalities

Tags: javascript, frameworks, refactoring, extendscript

I'm using a nice framework for Adobe ExtendScript called Extendables. I forked the project here: https://github.com/daluu/Extendables

A problem though is that in some ways using the framework is worse than not because the framework extends javascript objects with more functionality. And on an initial review of the code files, they seem rather interdependent such that it will take some work to uncouple the strict dependencies to make it optional/configurable to load only what you need and skip the rest in case of issues with particular features (i.e. you can just not load/include what you don't use - I don't think that's currently possible, although I might be mistaken). See the issue tracker in my project for details but in general the issues encountered using the full framework is failure of try/catch blocks and object iteration includes unintented properties.

For me, I'd just like at a minimum to make all functionality optional and just load the logger and Jasmine test framework as those are the only two feature/modules that I really use with Extendables. I don't care for the extensions to strings, files, object, arrays, etc.

As I'm a novice in javascript/ExtendScript, and this is not a trivially simple javascript framework, I could use suggestions on how to decouple the dependencies so that every module (baring it's dependendencies) can be optionally loaded, and where there are dependencies we can group into sets as in you can load or not load this set of features.

Sorry that I can't include code snippets as its too much to post, you can find it in my Github fork.

Not sure if this is best StackExchange site to post but starting here.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to extract the log module from this file:

https://github.com/daluu/Extendables/blob/master/core-packages/logging/lib/index.jsx

Try to use it like this (not tested):

```
#include "core-packages/logging/lib/index.jsx"
Log.debug("Log this");
```

You might need to adjust some things in there e.g. `Folder.extendables` does not exist in ExtendScript. Also `exports.Log` at the end will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The log module by itself among others can't be used as is, and it's not just from the exports and Folder.extendables. Most modules have interdependencies on other modules, all of them extending one another (arrays, strings, object). I had to rewrite some code to call native JS rather than the prototype JS extensions to some objects (array, string, etc.) so that it can purely be used standalone (or not). The reworked log module can be seen here: https://github.com/daluu/Extendables/blob/unextendables/core-packages/logging/lib/index.jsx